# Presenting a View Controller from an custom UIView (xib-file)

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` subclass (`AccountInfoModal`) that is presented on top of a `ViewController` by adding it as a subview. The `AccountInfoModal` has a button, that should lead to another `ViewController` being presented. 
Initializing that other `ViewController` isn't the problem. Presenting it is.

Since `AccountInfoModal` isn't a `ViewController` I can't use `.present(viewControllerToPresent...)`.

How do I present another ViewController from inside a UIView. I cannot figure it out.

EDIT: 
I have implemented this suggestion:

```
let underlyingVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
underlyingVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGSignInViewController", sender: nil)
```

But it causes a crash in the last line (Could not load NIB in bundle:...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

in AccountInfoModal file create a protocol above AccountInfoModal class :

```
protocol AccountInfoModalDelegate : class {
func willPresentingViewController(){
}
```

inside AccountInfoModal class define `delegate` variable :

```
weak var delegate?
```

inside button action call :

```
delegate?.willPresentingViewController()
```

in ViewController file add this following :

```
extension ViewController :  AccountInfoModalDelegate {
    func willPresentingViewController(){
    let vc = AnotherVC()
    self.present(vc, animated : true, completion : nil)
     }
}
```

Last step, set instance of AccountInfoModal `delegate = self` at where you call to present AccountInfoModal view

Answer (score 0):

Give `AccountInfoModal` a property, containingViewController. Set it when you install the `AccountInfoModal` view as a subview. Then use that to present the other view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest possible way - Just present that UIViewController from the root UIViewController:

```
let vc = UIViewController() //Your UIViewController
let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController //UIViewController from where you will present your UIViewController
rootVC?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)    //Present method
```